# Why does `int ;` compile fine in C, but not in C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, language-lawyer, variable-declaration

Consider the following program (see live demo [here](http://ideone.com/504P4P)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
      int ;  // Missing variable name
      puts("Surprise");
}
```

My compiler, gcc 4.8.1, gives the below warning:

> [Warning] useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]

Why does it compile fine? Shouldn't I get a compiler error? g++ 4.8.1 gives the following error when I compile it as a C++ program:

> [Error] declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]

Comment: @Nawaz: Is it explicitly said by language specification?

Comment: It's useless, I'd be surprised if the compiler omitted any instructions for that empty declaration.

Comment: It is explicitly said by the C++ standard: "**[dcl.dcl]/5** In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a *class-specifier*, an *elaborated-type-specifier*
with a *class-key* (9.1), or an *enum-specifier*." I'm not familiar with the C standard sufficiently well to cite chapter and verse.

Comment: "produces warning" is not "compiles fine".

Comment: Who would want to write `int;` and compile his code? I dont see what the fuss is all about.

Comment: The names of unused parameters may be omitted, it suppresses the unused parameter warning. This is the local-variable equivalent of the same thing. I would not want that to compile cleanly though, it is definitely worthy of a warning. It looks like a typo.

Comment: Well, you can define multiple locals at the same time (`int a, b, c;`), right? `int ;` just looks like a special case of the same thing, with 0 declared locals :D

Comment: @Luaan: ... And that special case is explicitly outlawed by the standard in both C and C++.

Comment: Recompile with `-Werror`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The C standard says

> A declaration other than a static_assert declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration.

C++ says

> In a simple-declaration, the optional init-declarator-list can be omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration.

A violation of this in either language requires a diagnostic. The standards do not talk about compiler errors or warnings. A warning is a diagnostic.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the standard requires translation to fail on certain violations? An "error" could be defined as a violation that produces a diagnostic and failure, and a "warning" is one that produces a diagnostic and no failure.

Comment: @tepples No, the standard only requires a diagnostic. It doesn't require (but allows) an invalid program to be rejected.

Comment: it means that e.g. `struct { int a; };`  declares a struct member, but this is not enough.

Comment: @n.m.: so name of structure is necessary here. right?

Comment: Either a tag or a declarator is needed. Tag is `struct a { ... }`. and declarator is `struct { ...} a`. A declarator can be a variable name or a typedef name (if there's typedef keyword).

Answer (score 36):

Your code is illegal (i.e. erroneous, ill-formed, constraint-violating) in both C and C++. The reason you get a "warning" in one language and "error" in another is just a quirk of your compiler and your compiler setup. After all, neither language really formally differentiates between "warnings" and "errors". GCC under its default settings just happens to be more permissive in C mode (mostly for historical reasons).

Use `-pedantic-errors` in GCC, and you will get an "error" in C code as well. (Note that `-pedantic-errors` does not simply blindly turn all "warnings" into "errors". It attempts to report only actual *constraint violations* as "errors".)

Answer (score 18):

The syntax of declaration is defined as (omitting *init-declarator-list* and *init-declarator*):

> #### C11 6.7 Declarations
>
> ```
> declaration:
>     declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list opt ;
>     static_assert-declaration
> declaration-specifiers:
>     storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
>     type-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
>     type-qualifier declaration-specifiers opt
>     function-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
>     alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers opt
> ```

Note that *declaration-specifiers* is defined recursively, but each with an **opt** indicates it's optional.

Also, the following clause 6 states:

> The declaration specifiers consist of a sequence of specifiers that indicate the linkage,
> storage duration, and part of the type of the entities that the declarators denote. The initdeclarator-list is a comma-separated sequence of declarators, each of which may have additional type information, or an initializer, or both. The declarators contain the identifiers **(if any)** being declared.

Note the words *if any*.