# Why doesn't GCC show any errors on an anonymous variable?

Tags: c++, variables, gcc, anonymous

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273550/why-does-int-compile-fine-in-c-but-not-in-c) question that explains how anonymous variables are invalid in C++.

But the following program compiles without any warning or errors on GCC 7.2 (even with `-Wall`) - [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/mTpqL2):

```
int main() {
    int (*); // anonymous variable?
}
```

Here, this is apparently also an integer type anonymous variable. So, why GCC does not show any errors or warnings? Is this a GCC bug?

Comment: What compiler flags did you use?

Comment: @StoryTeller I used  g++ -Wall prog.cpp

Comment: [This](https://godbolt.org/g/dV14P1) is indeed surprising. @Jayesh Write all relevant information in your question.

Comment: Indeed, with `-c -Wall -Wextra` the `g++-7`  compiler says nothing but `clang++-5.0` gives an error: *expected expression* on the closing paren. Perhaps it might be some compiler bug (I don't know who is wrong).

Comment: It seems the "buggy" behaviour only appears when parentheses are used

Comment: @PasserBy - Parentheses with an asterisk. Removing the asterisk [produces a warning](https://godbolt.org/g/ENJsrb).

Comment: @StoryTeller Since its being parsed as creating a temporary `int`, I'd say its not the same thing

Comment: I didn't check this case at all, but gcc has weak heuristics to disable warnings in some cases: - has already been warned about, - is between parentheses, - is unnamed, etc.

Comment: @PasserBy - Is it creating a temporary? `int()` is a function type. The plot thickens

Comment: @PasserBy - Furthermore, [forcing it to be a temporary (by replacing `()` with `{}`)](https://godbolt.org/g/dy3Krb), produces absolutely no diagnostic.

Comment: Report it to gcc's bugzilla?

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm confused :) For argument's sake, since there should be no such thing as anonymous function declarations and hence it should be parsed as an expression statement. I have no idea what's going on with `{}`

Comment: @PasserBy - Well, I think GCC is confused as well. `int()` is a type, just like `int*` is a type. They should produce identical errors. And yet, they don't. `int{}` is just some added silliness.

Comment: `int(&*&&&*&);` compiles too in gcc7 !

Answer (score 5):

There have been bugs recorded with gcc and how it detects variables for example I was using it to compile a simple program and it gave an error saying variable may be uninitialized when it have been. It is just a bug in the compiler. For example see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55985

Comment: The response was the issue has been fixed since at least gcc 5.3. OP's problem persists even for gcc 7.2

Comment: The problem does still persist as I have encountered this error in 7.2 the bug may have just been fixed in this individual case or something broke in a later update.