# Why is "static;" valid C syntax?

Tags: c, syntax, grammar, c11

I am looking at the [C11 Standard PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf#page=481) **(Page 463)**, and I am confused about the lexical grammar of declarations. It seems like code like this one seems to be grammatically valid in C11:

```c
static;
static const int;
long int const typedef long;
```

even though there does not seem to be any use for such a declaration.

---

To be specific, it's this part here which confuses me:

```
declaration: 
  declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list<opt> ;

declaration-specifiers:
  storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers<opt>
  type-specifier declaration-specifiers<opt>
  type-qualifier declaration-specifiers<opt>
  function-specifier declaration-specifiers<opt>
  alignment-specifier declaration-specifiers<opt>
```

It seems like init-declarator-list in a declaration has been made explicitly optional. Is there any use for declarations without it?

Comment: It seems to contradict the [first constraint](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p2) though:  *A declaration other than a static_assert declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration.*

Comment: @Julius Declarators are optional in parameter lists of function prototypes.

Comment: Related: [Why does `int ;` compile fine in C, but not in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33273550/10871073)

Comment: I see there is a constraint! But I still don't understand why it was made optional in the grammar. Parameter lists don't seem to reference the declaration nonterminal?

Comment: Maybe it was (accidentally) allowed in the past, and they've maintained compatibility by allowing the compiler to continue accepting it (albeit with a diagnostic). /// Or maybe they like defining things in terms of (possibly empty) lists in the grammar, and add constraints where required.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: A “declaration” in a function prototype is not the *declaration* grammar token asked about in this question; it is a *parameter-declaration* token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(That is not the C standard; it is an unofficial draft. And page 463 is non-normative text—it is just informative and not a binding part of the standard. This answer uses the official C 2018 standard, which has only technical corrections and clarifications from the 2011 standard.)

Speaking only to the formal grammar in the C standard, a *declaration* production, shown in C 2018 6.7 1, may be *declaration-specifiers* *init-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> `;`. In that, *declaration-specifiers* may produce *storage-class-specifier* *declaration-specifiers*<sub>opt</sub>, and *init-declarator-list* may be absent, giving *storage-class-specifier* *declaration-specifiers*<sub>opt</sub> `;`. Then the latter *declaration-specifiers* may be absent, giving *storage-class-specifier* `;`, which finally can produce `static` `;`.

However, the rules of the C standard go beyond the grammar. C 2018 6.7 2 says:

> A declaration other than a static_assert declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration.

The *declaration* `static` `;` does not declare a declarator, a tag, or any member of an enumeration, so it violates this constraint. Then a conforming C implementation must issue a diagnostic message for it, although it may nonetheless accept it.

`static` `const` `int` `;` and `long` `int` `const` `typedef` `long` `;` also violate this constraint.

Further, C 2018 6.7.2 2 says:

> At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,…

Since `static` `;` has no type specifier, such as `void`, `int`, or `long double _Complex`, it violates this constraint as well.

`static` `const` `int` `;` and `long` `int` `const` `typedef` `long` `;` do not violate this constraint.

> It seems like init-declarator-list in a declaration has been made explicitly optional. Is there any use for declarations without it?

Yes, we can usefully declare structure, union, and enumeration tags, as in `struct foo { int x; };`. This declares the type `struct foo` and has no *init-declarator* (at the main level; there is one nested inside, of course).

We can also declare enumeration constants, as in `struct foo { apple, banana };`. This has no *init-declarator* at any level.

The fact that there are useful declarations with no *init-declarator* meant that either *init-declarator* had to be kept optional in the production or the production had to be split into two productions, one of which allowed declaring structures and such with no *init-declarator* and one of which produced declarations with a mandatory *init-declarator*. Presumably the nuisance of complicating the grammar presentation was not considered worth the benefit of reducing the semantic constraints.